# Two anchors and two tables, need to show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two anchors and two tables, upon clicking anchor 1, I want table1 to appear and on clicking anchor2 table 1 must be closed and table 2 should appear.

My code in JavaScript for toggling between show and hide:

```
function setTable(what) {
    if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

My two anchors:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="setTable('aboutdialog');return false" id="iam">I am</a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="#" onclick="setTable('stab');return false" id="photo">Photo</a>
</td>
```

My two table:

```
<table id="aboutdialog" title="Me mE me!!" style="display:none;" >
<table width="100%" id="stab" style="display:none;width:58%;height: 60%;">
```

Now it works for me like, on clicking the anchor1 for the first time it shows table 1 and on second click hides table1. Same for anchor2.

But I want upon clicking anchor1 to close table 2 if opened and display table1 alone vice versa for anchor2.

Comment: There's quite a few people who've assisted here. May I suggest you reply to and/or upvote the answers that you thought would have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the function

```
function setTable(what){

   if(what=="aboutdialog"){
      document.getElementById("aboutdialog").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("stab").style.display="none";
   }
   else if(what=="stab"){
      document.getElementById("aboutdialog").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("stab").style.display="block";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank U so Much.. It worked.. Actually i was stuck for 2 days in this.. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Without jQuery

```
    <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="setTable('aboutdialog', 'stab');return false" id="iam">I am</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="setTable('stab', 'aboutdialog');return false" id="photo">Photo</a>
    </td>
```

then

```
function setTable(what, second) {
    if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "none";
    } else if (document.getElementById(what).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(what).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(second).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3zwNQ/)

---

A jQuery solution might look like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--Add a class trigger to the anchor elements-->
            <a href="#aboutdialog" id="iam" class="trigger">I am</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <!--Add a class trigger to the anchor elements-->
            <a href="#stab" id="photo" class="trigger">Photo</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--Add a class target to the tables elements-->
<table id="aboutdialog" title="Me mE me!!" style="display:none;" class="target">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--Add a class target to the tables elements-->
<table width="100%" id="stab" style="display:none;width:58%;height: 60%;" class="target">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    var $targets = $('.target');
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        //hide all other target elements
        $targets.not(id).hide();
        //toggle the display of current element
        $(id).toggle()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pCc5a/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#iam').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('#aboutdialog').show().siblings('#stab').hide();
});

$('#photo').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('#stab').show().siblings('#aboutdialog').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/)

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#iam').click(function(){
        $('#aboutdialog').show();
        $('#stab').hide();
    });

    $('#photo').click(function(){
        $('#stab').show();
        $('#aboutdialog').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**live example is here >>**](http://jsfiddle.net/QXWkb/)

Simple with the jquery library :

```
$('#iam').click(function(){
    $('#aboutdialog').show().siblings('table').hide();
});
$('#photo').click(function(){
    $('#newdialog').show().siblings('table').hide();
});
```

html

```
<a href="#" onclick="setTable('aboutdialog');return false" id="iam">I am</a></td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="setTable('stab');return false" id="photo">Photo</a></td>

<table id="aboutdialog" title="Me mE me!!" style="display:none;" >
<tr><th>abc</th></tr>
</table>

<table id="newdialog" title="Me mE me!!" style="display:none;" >
<tr><th>yaskjd</th></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {'iam': 'aboutdialog', 'photo': 'stab'};
    $('#iam, #photo').on('click', function() {
        $('#aboutdialog, #stab').hide();
        $('#' + options.($(this).attr('id'))).show();
    });
});
```